# hostapd 802.11n/ac bandwith

Tags: networking, wifi, wireless, hostapd

Some 802.11* standards support multiple bandwiths (20MHz-40MHz-...) and accordingly higher bandwith (in Mb/second)...

with this hostapd configuration file, its not entirely clear if we can manually set this bandwith? 
https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/hostapd/hostapd.conf

Comment: Is this Pi related? What model Pi do you have? What wifi device? Wich OS + version? What have you tried already? Please update our question with relevant details.

Comment: If you searched the file in your link for `20 MHz` or `40 MHz`, you would've found the answer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the sections **IEEE 802.11n related configuration** (IEEE 802.11n in the 2.4GHz band is available e.g. with the built-in Wifi chip of the Raspberry Pi 3B) and **IEEE 802.11ac related configuration** in case your wifi chip is capable of IEEE802.11ac (as is the built-in wifi chip of the Raspberry Pi 3B+).

The comments in the config file already give you many indications, how to use it.

One example for 40MHz wide channel in the 2.4GHz band (IEEE 802.11n):

```
hw_mode=g
channel=1
ieee80211n=1
ht_capab=[HT40+]
```

Comment: would you also want/need `wmm_enabled=1`

Comment: @Jaromanda X As wmm_enabled relates to QoS I do not think you need it in order to have wider channels.

Comment: Reading the file in the OP link, it states: *Note: You will also need to enable WMM for full HT functionality.* - but yeah, that relates to other HT functionality I guess

Comment: @Jaromanda X  That is also my understanding.